# Module not found: Can't resolve 'base64-js' error every time I try to create and run a next app

Tags: next.js, compiler-errors, modulenotfounderror

After creating a nextjs app, I tried running npm run dev and got this error:

```
error ../../node_modules/buffer/index.js:11:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'base64-js'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/util/util.js
./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/match-remote-pattern.js
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/image-loader.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/image-component.js
```

I have tried installing, reinstalling and updating node, npm, next and also tried installing the base64-js module. I also tried to trace the error to the file mentioned in the error, but was not able to find anything.

Please let me know if anyone has a solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1. Delete the "node_modules" folder
2. Remove the "package-lock.json" file
3. run "npm install"